# Is there a way to make an XML file in RDB using Jena?

Tags: jena, xmlreader, triplestore

I used apache-jena-3.1.0 and JDBC to read and save XML files on a table (nodes, prefixes, quads, and trips) that was pre-made in MariaDB.

I wonder if I can make an XML file by reading MariaDB using Apache-jena.
And I wonder if I can save the stored data (nodes, prefixes, and triples) back to MariaDB in its original form (appropriate for RDB).

I am constantly trying to search for related jar or mathod.

Thank you.

Comment: Apache Jena no longer has support for storing RDF data in SQL databases. It used to have a subsystem called "SDB" which was removed at Jena 3.17.0. The current Jena version is 4.6.1 and the project no longer supports SDB. It used its own custom database schema. If Jena did not write the database in the first place, then Jena SDB will not be able to read it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)
I know that SDB is no longer supported, but I am going to use SDB.
When using SDB, is there a method to save the Triple I made in SDB and a method to read Triple in SDB?
Thank you.

Comment: Use the Jena API to read and write triples, with via GraphSDB, or via the RDF API where they are called Statements. The underlying code will put triples back together again. The SQL schema is in the code.

Comment: Do you mean "Model model = SDBFactory.connectDefaultModel(store); model.read(is, null);"?
I found it on the Jena site.
1. Use the command utility sdbload 2.Use one of the Jena model.read operations 3.Use the Jena model.add

Comment: The model is the data in the database -- read will load data _into_ the model and hence database.  You want the model.list* and model.get* operations to pull data from the database.

Comment: You mean "model.read(InputStream in, String base)"is just read from database?
I ran "Model = SDBFactory.connectDefaultModel(store);" and "model.read(is, null);" and it was saved in my MariaDB "triple, nods, prefixes" table

Comment: Other way round to the first part and as you describe the second part.  "read" consumes and parses the input stream and add statements into the model i.e. into the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and for answering for me, who is ignorant.
There are still a lot of questions left, but I'm trying to solve them by myself.
Thank you again.